# VSCode doesn't type check `.ts` files in a lerna monorepo

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, lerna

I've set up a simple [lerna](https://github.com/lerna/lerna) monorepo (using [Yarn workspaces](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/workspaces/)) with 3 typescript project bootstrapped using https://github.com/alexjoverm/typescript-library-starter

The project structure looks like:

```
 - servir/
   - lerna.json
   - package.json
   - packages/
     - core/
       - src/
       - tsconfig.json
       - package.json
     - server/
       - src/
       - tsconfig.json
       - package.json
     - client/
       - src/
       - tsconfig.json
       - package.json
```

For some reason, VSCode refuses to do typechecking for .ts files in those projects as validated by typing in `const x: number = false` (in: `packages/core/src/core.ts`) and not getting any error.

Reproduce by cloning this repo: https://gitlab.com/tsuberim/serv.git

What could be the problem?

Comment: did you try adding typescript package as a devdependency?

Comment: vscode has a builtin typescript compiler. Plus it works perfectly when I clone "Typescript library starter" outside of my lerna project. I assume it has something to do with lerna confusing VScode somehow